# Making PS1 prompt refreshable

Tags: bash, script, colors, prompt, ps1

I want my prompt to be changed based on an output of a certain command. and based on the command result to add a color.

example:
run the command:

```
cphaprob stat | grep local | awk '{ print $NF }'`
```

(this will show the last word only.

Now, if the result is "attention", I want the prompt to be:

```
PS1='[\t][\u@\h]\[\e[0;92m\][attention]\[\e[0m\]# '
```

so the word "attention" will be green.

However if the word will be "down" I want the prompt to be in different color:

```
PS1='[\t][\u@\h]\[\e[4;91m\][Down]\[\e[0m\]# '
```

I want the change to be "on-the-fly" meaning on each new line (pressing Enter) I want the prompt to be updated based on the result.

If possible this should somehow be made permanent via .bashrc.

Any ideas on how to make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me (using bash 4.2.37):

```
PS1='[\t][\u@\h][$(i=$(cphaprob stat|grep local|awk "{print \$NF}")
u=0
case $i in
(Active|attention) c=92;;
(Down|Error) u=4; c=91;;
(Standby) c=93;;
(Ready) c=94;;
(*) c=95 ;;
esac
printf "\033[%s;%sm%s\033[0m" $u $c $i
)]# '
```

Comment: Are "attention" and "Down" the only possible values?

Comment: So what colors are you expecting for the other values ?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Answer updated again and made simpler. You should put that code as is in your .bashrc meaning you shouldn't double the backslash in `\$NF`.

Comment: Hi, If I'm not putting the double backslash I'm getting syntax error. is there a way to chat here? i need few explenations. thanks

Comment: What OS and what shell are you using (precisely) ?

Comment: and did you just cut and paste that piece of code in you .bashrc or did you do something else ? What precise error message did you get ?

Comment: it's CheckPoint Firewall Gaia Bash. how can I know which bash version I'm using ?

Comment: This one did it well. PS1='[\t][Expert@$HOSTNAME]$(i=$(cphaprob stat|grep local|awk "{print \\$NF}")
case $i in
(attention) printf "\[\e[4;92m\][Active attention]\[\e[0m\]" ;;
(Active) printf "\[\e[0;92m\][Active]\[\e[0m\]" ;;
(Standby) printf "\[\e[0;93m\][Standby]\[\e[0m\]" ;;
(Down) printf "\[\e[4;91m\][Down]\[\e[0m\]" ;;
(Ready) printf "\[\e[4;96m\][Ready]\[\e[0m\]" ;;
(*) printf "\[\e[0;101m\][Error]\[\e[0m\]" ;;

esac
)# '

Comment: Glad you made it. To get which bash version you are using, run `bash --version`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to leverage the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable as well as the `PS1` variable, redefining the `PS1` variable inside `PROMPT_COMMAND`. I'll let you reference other answers for specifics on how to accomplish your specific need, but this will resolve the request to update "on-the-fly." This was a challenge I ran into when working through including the exit status in each new prompt (if non-zero).

For example, my bash config files 'build' a PS1 prompt, which is subsequently set using the following command (where variable `ps1` represents what I want my `PS1` variable to be):

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="export PS1=\"$ps1\""
```

Here's my full `.bash_prompt` file for your reference (which I simply include from `.bashrc`):
https://gist.github.com/austinbeam/10930268